# Java - multiple screens gui application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

What is the best way to create a java application with multiple screens? For example, pressing a button switches to the next screen. Should I use a JFrame for each screen?

Thanks

Comment: Define "screen". Window? Actual (full) screen?

Comment: No, use a CardLayout to swap "views". Whatever you do, avoid throwing a bunch of JFrames at the user. Please read [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).